# i want to create matrix from csv file

Tags: python, csv, matrix

I want to create a matrix from CSV file.

Here's what I've tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv-path', usecols=[0,1], names=['A', 'B'])
pd.pivot_table(df,columns='A', values='B')
```

output : `[9197337 rows x 2 columns]`.

I want to take fewer rows like I want to make a matrix of first 100 entries or 1000. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `csv` module only deals in complete files, it would be easiest to extract the lines of interest before you use it. You could do this before running your program with the Unix `head` utility. Here's one way that should work in Python:

```
with open("csv-path") as inf, open("mod_csv_path", "w") as outf:
    for i in range(1000):
        outf.write(inf.readline())
```

Obviously you'd then read "mod_csv_path" rather than "csv-path' as the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas seems to be the right approach ? Can you provide a sample of your CSV file.

Also, with pandas, you can limit the size of your dataframe:

```
limited_df = df.head(num_elements)
```